# Не получается программно получить width и height от View

Tags: android, view, height, width

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="400px" 
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p;

    DisplayMetrics metrics;

    int displayWidth;
    int displayHeight;

    int viewWidth;
    int viewHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //получаем размеры интересующего нашего View
        viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
        viewHeight = textView.getHeight();

        //выводим данные о View (проверим, насколько точно будут выведены значения (сравним со значениями, которые мы передали в xml файле)
        //для этого давайте использовать Log.
        Log.i("userTest2020", String.valueOf("view width = "+viewWidth+"\n"+"view height = "+viewHeight));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //получаем размеры интересующего нашего View
        //viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
        //viewHeight = textView.getHeight();

        //выводим данные о View (проверим, насколько точно будут выведены значения (сравним со значениями, которые мы передали в xml файле)
        //для этого давайте использовать Log.
        Log.i("userTest2020", String.valueOf("view width = "+viewWidth+"\n"+"view height = "+viewHeight));
    }
}
```

Result

```
2020-03-30 07:48:51.994 28754-28754/com.bignerdranch.testresoulutionchanges I/userTest2020: view width = 0
    view height = 0
2020-03-30 07:48:52.004 28754-28754/com.bignerdranch.testresoulutionchanges I/userTest2020: view width = 0
    view height = 0
```

В чем проблема?

на заметку:

Вначале пробовал в xml передать значения width и height с помощью "dp".

Потом сменил на "px".

Также кроме onCreate использовал и в onResume с целью увидеть, связано ли данная проблема с тем, что View xml просто не успел реализоваться.

Но судя по всему - пожалуй дело не в успевании. Пока у меня других догадок нет.

Поэтому и задал мой вопрос тут.

Все равно результат один и тот же.

Comment: @Marionette ответ довольно туманный. Не решил проблему. Можно указать в ответе пример кода, который возвращает не нулевое значение width и height?

Comment: Переопредилите onWindowsFocusChanged и там измеряйте

Comment: @Style-7 спасибо, сработала! А так. Как то инфо попадалась, что данный способ имеет какие то нежелательные побочные эффекты. Какие нежелательные ситуации могут быть и какие советы вы бы дали для избежания от них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема, но я нашёл решение:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewWidth = view.getWidth();
        viewHeight = view.getHeight();
    };
});
```

В решении было написано, что это связано с тем, что вид ещё не до конца нарисовался и добавился на экран.

Comment: Тоже помогло.  Хотя я ранее тоже пробовал этот вариант, но оказалось, что Log использовал в не правильном месте.